# File Deletion from uploaded files

Tags: java, spring, io

These program is for uploading multiple files and one file which is selected.

I have done with uploading multiple files and now I should list all files and delete one file from those list. I am able to list the files in console. But, my sir told me that is not the way.

MY question is how to list those files and delete one among them.

Explain me the concept of listing the upload files and selecting one file and delete.

Controller program is working fine for multiple file upload.

```
/*This is controller program*/

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder;

import com.javasampleapproach.uploadfile.storage.StorageService;

@Controller
public class UploadController {

    @Autowired
    StorageService storageService;

    List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String directoryWindows ="E://temp";

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String listUploadedFiles(Model model)
    {
        return "uploadForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("filefield") File fname,
                                   @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, 
                                   Model model) 
    {
        try
        {
            storageService.store(file);
            model.addAttribute("message", "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
            files.add(file.getOriginalFilename());

                String filename =fname.getName();

                System.out.println(filename);
                File folder=new File("E:\\temp\\"+filename+"\\");

                folder.mkdirs();
                System.out.println(folder);

                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                Path path = Paths.get("E:\\temp\\"+filename+"\\"+ file.getOriginalFilename());
                Files.write(path, bytes);

                listFilesForFolder(directoryWindows);


        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            model.addAttribute("message", "FAIL to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
        }
        return "uploadForm";
    }

    public void listFilesForFolder(String folder)
    {
        File directory=new File(folder);

        for (final File fileEntry : directory.listFiles()) 
        {
             System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
        }
     }


    @GetMapping("/gellallfiles")
    public String getListFiles( //@RequestParam("name") File first,
                                Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("files",
                files.stream()
                        .map(fileName -> MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                                .fromMethodName(UploadController.class, "getFile", fileName).build().toString())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        model.addAttribute("totalFiles", "TotalFiles: " + files.size());
        //String filesnames =first.getName();
        //System.out.println("welcome"+filesnames);
        return "listFiles";



    }

    @GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile(@PathVariable String filename) 
    {
        Resource file = storageService.loadFile(filename);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(file);
    }
}


/* This is html program*/

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <h2>List All Uploaded Files</h2>
    <div>
        <ul>

            <li th:each="file : ${files}">
                <a th:href="${file}" th:text="${file}" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        Enter File to Delete:<input type="text" name="name" id="id"/><br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="delete" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3 th:text="${totalFiles}"/>
        <a href="/">Back to UploadForm!</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>



[output][1]

/* This is how output is printed */
How can I list those files and select one among them and delete it.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzLVQ.png
```

Comment: suppose if you are using a database in your application can you store the filenames in the database. [link](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-fileupload-download-hibernate-example/)

Comment: i am working on frontend, so no database is used. My sir said, u can use  form fills and get it to controller. completely not getting concept